# Tons of 404 errors in Apache httpd log for static files with wrong Path

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, http-status-code-404

We have an Apache in front of a Tomcat, with the Tomcat serving both static and dynamic content. The Tomcat has gotten terribly slow since the number of users on the system increased, and we are trying to pinpoint the cause. We have other servers with double the number of open sessions in Tomcat with no problem.

In the Apache httpd log I am seeing thousands of 404 errors for static files with paths that don't exist in our application. The files exist and the path almost looks right, but it contains duplications and parts of other file paths in the system.

Example: we have this file in our system:

```
/assets/img/menu-toggler.png
```

In the httpd log I can see this:

```
[02/Oct/2014:12:22:16 +1000] "GET /assets/assets/css/assets/plugins/jqvmap/assets/assets/img/menu-toggler.png HTTP/1.1" 404 11947 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)"
[02/Oct/2014:12:22:16 +1000] "GET /assets/assets/plugins/gritter/assets/plugins/fullcalendar/assets/assets/img/menu-toggler.png HTTP/1.1" 404 11947 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)"
```

We have the folders `assets`, `plugins`, `jquery-validation`, etc in the system, but certainly not nested like that.

We also have correct GET requests for that file

```
[02/Oct/2014:12:37:23 +1000] "GET /assets/img/menu-toggler.png HTTP/1.1" 200 948 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)"
```

I believe that all these 404 errors are causing Tomcat to be slow. Question is: what could cause such weird GET requests with paths in the system that don't exist?

Comment: `Question is: what could cause such weird GET requests with paths in the system that don't exist?` Answer: Code which we can not see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: it was caused by relative paths for the static content. In case somebody else runs into this issue here is the explanation:The application used paths like

```
<img src="../assets/img/menu-toggler.png" alt="" />
```

for all static content. This worked except if some static content url was wrong. In this case a 404 error was returned. The 404 error page also included static content with relative paths. Those paths were resolved **relative to the content that original caused the 404**. Since that lead to a wrong url it would trigger another 404 error, and a cascade of 404 errors would ensue.

Example:

```
<img src="../assets/one/two/three/non_existent.png"/>
```

Absolute path is

```
www.myserver.com/assets/one/two/three/non_existent.png
```

Since the image is nonexistent a 404 error is returned. The 404 page has

```
<img src="../assets/error/404/404.png"/>
```

Path path is resolved relative to the first bad url

```
www.myserver.com/assets/one/two/assets/error/404/404.png
```

This leads to a cascade of erroneous paths, 404 errors, a production server that craps out, and headless chicken syndrome.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities :

> **1** - One of your dynamic pages is generating a bad URL and serves this URL to the clients who try to get the file from this bad URL.
>
> **2** - Someone who deliberately tries to DDoS your server by flooding him with bad requests.

Your log may also contain useful information such `IP` address or clients and `HTTP` referer that may guide you in your quest for answer.

The first option is more likely to be the good answer and can explain why your server performances are dropping and why the incriminated bad URL contain a duplicate part of themselves (something like a loop with a bad exit condition in one of your scripts ?)